# How to get the centroid of a set of points in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, centroids

I use PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extension.

I have a set of points in `the_geom` column from a table `myschema.myobjects`.  I want to create a select statement to get the centroid of this cluster, so from a select statement like this:

```
SELECT the_geom FROM myschema.myobjects
```

I need to find the correct syntax for a statement like:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid( (SELECT the_geom FROM myshema.myobjects) ));
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you have to use the union function like this

```
SELECT att1, st_centroid(st_union(geom)) as geom
FROM schema.table
GROUP BY att1;
```

so you can obtain centroid of point that have same attribute.

Answer (score 20):

PostGIS has two functions for combining multiple geometries into a single geometry that you can use as an input to `ST_Centroid`.

[`ST_Collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) simply combines a set of geometries without modifying them.

The alternative,[`ST_Union`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html), will "dissolve" multiple geometries and remove redundant components. This is probably not what you want for this application.

To see the difference, compare:

```
 SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_Union(geom))) FROM 
 (VALUES ('POINT (0 0)'), ('POINT (2 2)'), ('POINT (2 2)')) sq (geom);

 -- POINT(1 1)
```

and

```
 SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom))) FROM 
 (VALUES ('POINT (0 0)'), ('POINT (2 2)'), ('POINT (2 2)')) sq (geom);

 -- POINT(1.33333333333333 1.33333333333333)
```

In this case, `ST_Union` has removed the duplicated point, while `ST_Collect` has retained it.

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for performance use this query:

```
SELECT avg(ST_X(the_geom)) as lon, avg(ST_Y(the_geom)) as lat FROM table
```

it gives you more or less the same output as:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(the_geom))) FROM table
```

like in @dbaston answer, but is faster and doesn't use as much memory.